# Use 3GB Free Space to Access 30 GB info without Virtual Memory Paging?

Tags: algorithm

I have a quick question:

How can we Use a 3GB Free Space to Access roughly 30 GB of data without Virtual Memory or Compression? It's more of a Data Structure Question.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should somehow mimic the paging mechanism.

One way to do it is *hashing*<sup>1</sup>.

Hash all your data into bins, and store these bins in disk. In your main memory (RAM) you will only hold an array of pointers to disk. Once you need an address, you know where it is on disk by accessing the RAM and taking the pointer from the location `hash(address)`

You can of course optimize it to keep a portion of the data in memory - using the [principle of locality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_locality) - and hoping to get a *hit* - and avoid reloading a chunk from disk.

---

(1) The hashing does not have to be complex or uniformly distributed. I believe using the MSb's of the address will be just fine - and will actually mimic the paging mechanism better.

Comment: Is there a non-hash way? It's an interview question

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious way would be through a typical filesystem API with `read`, `write`, and `seek` functions.